# List Instances not created on Feature Activation for Initial Deployment

Tags: 2010, feature-activation

I have two features, a Content Type feature that contains the content type and list definitions, and a List feature that creates the List Instances from the list definitions.  Both features auto-activate on Central Admin.

When I deploy my solution, both features are activated, and the content type/definitions are created, but the List instances are not.  If I deactivate my List feature and re-activate it, the List instances are created at that point.

Any idea why they wouldn't be created on solution deployment?  Within the package, the Content type feature comes before the List feature.

Edit: I've even split the List Instance creation out into another solution package.  Same issue persists.  I'm making sure to perform a restart of w3svc in between the deployment of the solution with the List definitions and solution with the List instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you created your list instance based on a Custom list, which you deploy in another feature (Content types & List definition in feature 1 - Site Collection Scope should be fine), and the list Instances in feature 2 (probably Web Level), then you should add another attribute (FeatureId) to your 2nd feature specifying the Id of the 1st feature. Also do not forget to have the TemplateType specified (which most like it is, but just to make sure)

Beside that, Patel's suggestion is also important, just make sure dependency is put on the 2nd Feature (Instance) by specifying GUID of 1st feature (CT & List definition one).

```
<ListInstance 
  CustomSchema = string
  Description = "Text"
  DocumentTemplate = integer
  **FeatureId = "<GUID of 1st FEATURE HERE>"**
  Hidden = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  HyperlinkBaseUrl = string
  Id = Text
  OnQuickLaunch = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  QuickLaunchUrl = "Text"
  RootWebOnly = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  TemplateType = Integer
  Title = "Text"
  Url = "Text"
  VersioningEnabled = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
</ListInstance>
```

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: Yes, I have the FeatureId set in the List Instance Elements.xml, as well as the appropriate TemplateType from my List Definition.  I'm still not seeing them created on feature activation.  FWIW while I have a Receiver, I do not define FeatureActivating/Installing, only FeatureDeactivating (to delete the lists).

Comment: at least from configuration standpoint you should be set. did u tried only from VS or via STSADM (manual activation) of your parent feature? it is known that Visual Studio caches configurations, etc. which occasionally induces unexpected behavior.

Comment: Both VS and PowerShell exhibit the same issue.

Comment: i'm afraid that without more details i can't help further.

Comment: Are you aware of a simple tutorial on creating List Instances via the FeatureActivated method?  That might help.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/bhushangawale/creating-list-using-list-definition-code-behind-approach/

Comment: Ok, did that, and the first time I upload the solution via PowerShell, the lists are created just fine via the Feature Activated method.  If I deactivate the Solution (which deletes the List Instances in a FeatureUninstalling method), then reactivate it, no luck.  Same if I retract, remove, reupload the solution, no such luck in creating the list instances (despite the *feature* being in the Active state!).  No luck in resetting IIS, SharePoint Admin or Timer Services.  I'm at a loss as to why the feature itself would be activated, but the FeatureActivated method looks to be ignored.

Comment: upon deactivation is your CT and list removed? one other thing important related to content types is that as soon as you add items to a list based on a CT, you cannot delete the CT due to being used - which also implies the list, unless you empty the Recycle Bin. For Upgrade scenarios it is recomanded to use the Feature upgrade.

Comment: Yes, both are removed.  The behavior is just bizarre.  If I build a solution, deploy it, things are created fine (the List Instances) based on the definition, thanks to your link above.  If I retract and then immediately redeploy that solution, the FeatureActivated for the feature containing the List Instance creation is just skipped outright!  If I retract, remove, redeploy, same issue.  I just don't get why the FeatureActivated method is completely skipped.

Comment: In the end, the issue turned out to be not deactivating the feature containing the List creation prior to retracting the solution.  The link you provided helped significantly as well.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a dependency issue. Setting FEATURE dependency may resolve the issue. The FEATURE which creates List instance should depend on FEATURE which creates content types and list definition. Feature dependency are supported in FEATURE designer of VS.NET 2010.

Comment: Set an appropriate feature dep and I get the same result.  The List feature is activated, but the List instances haven't been created.  Deactivate the List feature, re-activate it, and the List Instances are created.